# How to get URL of a folder stored in S3 storage?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm new to AWS and I'm trying to do a very simple thing i.e to get the url of the project folder I've uploaded to my S3 storage so that I can pass that URL to beanstalk to upload the code. I've tried making the folder public but it doesn't work. As shown in the third image labeled error I'm not getting the option to get the URL of the stored folder.

This is what I've done.

[s3 folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfZis.jpg)

[s3 folder made public](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnXJY.jpg)

[cannot get folder url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hBwI.jpg)

Comment: You have to provide exactly what you want to do, what your tried and why exactly it does not work (error messages, screenshots), because writhing "it doesn't work" is not specific.

Comment: There is no error shown on your screenshots.

Comment: @Marcin Yes but I cannot get the URL of the folder I've uploaded to it.

Comment: Folders don't have urls, only objects. Sorry, I don't understand what do you want to do. You have to upload zip to EB, not any folders anyway. So why would you need a folder url if it existed?

Comment: I wanted to upload the code in it to run using beanstalk.

Comment: You have to download it, zip it, and upload to EB. Or use CodePipeline to perform these actions automatically.

Comment: Ok, thank you, will try it.